# cannot display UIImage one after one

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

I'm kind of stuck since this morning... i'm trying to load an image after another image but... it doesnt work... i don't even have my first image displayed ...

There is my code :

```
- (void) checkResources
{

    NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [manager enumeratorAtPath:bundleRoot];


    NSString *cuttedName;
    NSString *cuttedName1;



  for (NSString *path in direnum)
    {

        if ([[path pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mp4"])
        {
            cuttedName1 = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ressources/" withString:@""];
            cuttedName = [cuttedName1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".mp4" withString:@""];
            if ([cuttedName isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]]) 
            {
                NSString *media = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", bundleRoot, path];
                [self startSlideShow:media];
            }
        }
        else if ([[path pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mov"])
        {
            cuttedName1 = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ressources/" withString:@""];
            cuttedName = [cuttedName1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".mov" withString:@""];
            if ([cuttedName isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]]) 
            {
                NSString *media = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", bundleRoot, path];
                [self startSlideShow:media];
            }
        }
        else  if ([[path pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"])
        {
            cuttedName1 = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ressources/" withString:@""];
            cuttedName = [cuttedName1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@""];
            if ([cuttedName isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]]) 
            {
                NSString *media = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", bundleRoot, path];
                num++;
            [self startImage:media];
            }
        }
    }

}
- (void) startImage:(NSString *)nameFile
{
    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 500);

    UIImageView *imageView;
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"]];
    NSLog(@"IAMGE %@", imageView.image);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkResources) withObject:nil afterDelay:10]; // this will give time for UI to update itself.. 
    [imageView release];

    }

- (void) startSlideShow:(NSString *)nameFile
{    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:nameFile];//[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"mov"]];




    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = 
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
   // NSLog(@" URL : %@", url);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 600);

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
   }



-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification*)notification
{ 
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self      
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayer];

    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
       // [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    }


    //[[moviePlayer release] addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];


    num++;
    [self checkResources];
}
```

Don't mind about the goal of my code :) i just  want to display the uiimage, then when the method checkResources is called after displayed the first image i will send to startImage another image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two main problem that can be in your code.. no other problem can be.

1) Your UI doesn't update because of continuous addSubview methods..

2) Your UIImage is null..

To check 1)

change

```
[self checkResources];
```

to

```
[self performselector:@selector(checkResources) withObject:nil afterDelay:3] // this will give time for UI to update itself..
```

use Auto Complete for the above code...might be spelling mistakes..

To check 2)

simply `NSlog imageview.image` .. this will tell if image view image is null or not..

Comment: Ok i did but i still have a probleme. I'm trying to explain what i'm doing :

checkRessources call firstly my method "startImage:(NSString *)nameFile"

Then when startImage is done, i do what you did then checkRessources is called but now checkRessource will load another method which display a video.

The problem is : the video is displayed whitout showing firstly the image... it is like the video doesnt give enough time to the uimage to be display

Comment: if i don't load the method to play the video the image is well loaded and displayed

Comment: change the delay to a larger value .. and try again .. other wise post your whole code.. of both functions

Comment: what i want it is : displaying an uimage, then video, then image or video depends of the name of the file ( 0 or 1 or 2 etc... )

video after video it is ok... but not with image

Comment: what i think is you try breakpoints and check if the image successfully is added to screen.. addsubview method passes successfully.. and then also make sure ..check resources is again called after 10 seconds only.. use breakpoints to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your real code you have a infinite loop. One method calls the other..
otherwise: Where is the problem?

Comment: it is really my real code, after loaded the image checkRessource will load another method which display a video.

Comment: please show your WHOLE code for the problem and ask a more specific question. we cannot help like that.

Comment: what i want it is : displaying an uimage, then video, then image or video depends of the name of the file ( 0 or 1 or 2 etc... )

video after video it is ok... but not with image

Comment: you should do a return after each `[self startSlideShow:media]` or `[self startImage:media];` so no two action will be startet at once

Comment: Thanks man ! it works ! :) another question, just to abuse of you :p i would like to implement transition, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616628/movieplaybackdidfinish-and-transitions-effect

but i don't know how to could you help me ?